# Import image text in mysql db using Picasso in Android Listview

Tags: listview, android-imageview

In the code below, I have configured the db contents in mysql on the server to list view using json. Text files that contain images in the current db are read well, but it is not good to read the text and put it in the image view. I would like to use Picasso to put the image url in an image view or some other way.

```
  public void showList(){
          try {
              JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sJSON); //String sJSON
              jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_RESULTS); //JSONArray    jsonArray = null;

           for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

               c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); //JSONObject c;
               //String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);


               String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
               name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
               address = c.getString(TAG_ADD);


               String phone = c.getString(TAG_PHONE);
               String dlatitude = c.getString(TAG_LAT);
               String dlongitude = c.getString(TAG_LONG);


               lat = Double.parseDouble(dlatitude);
               longi = Double.parseDouble(dlongitude);

               Location curlocation = new Location("curpoint");
               curlocation.setLatitude(latitude);
               curlocation.setLongitude(longitude);

               Location datalocation = new Location("datapoint");
               datalocation.setLatitude(lat);
               datalocation.setLongitude(longi);

               distance = curlocation.distanceTo(datalocation);
               meter = Double.toString(distance);

               HashMap<String, String> location = new HashMap<String,String();

               //location.put(TAG_ID,id);
               location.put(TAG_IMAGE,image);
               location.put(TAG_NAME, name);
               location.put(TAG_ADD, address);
               location.put(TAG_PHONE, phone);
               location.put(TAG_LAT, dlatitude);
               location.put(TAG_LONG, dlongitude);

               location.put(TAG_DIS, "DISTANCE" + meter + "m");

               slocationList.add(location);

               ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(CurrentLocationActivity.this, slocationList, R.layout.list_item,new String[]{TAG_IMAGE,TAG_NAME, TAG_ADD, TAG_PHONE, TAG_LAT,TAG_LONG,TAG_DIS},new int[]{R.id.image, R.id.name, R.id.address, R.id.phone,R.id.latitude,R.id.longitude, R.id.distance});

               list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```